How to easily take a column of data in excel and turn it into a list in which each value repeats several times before continuing to the next value
Basically, I want a way to take a column of values, numerical or strings, in Excel, like this:








Val1


BigVal2


SmallVal3


MediumVal6



And turn it into this:








Val1


Val1


Val1


Val1


BigVal2


BigVal2


BigVal2


BigVal2


SmallVal3


SmallVal3


SmallVal3


SmallVal3


MediumVal6


MediumVal6


MediumVal6


MediumVal6



Now, obviously I can just ctrl c, drag mouse over 4 cells, and ctrl v. But the actual list that I am wanting to use is like 1000 values long. So if there is some way that I could convert one format to the other lickety-split that would be great.

What version of excel are you using? Newer versions of excel have formulas that can do this? VBA can also do this. Regardless, what have you tried so far? Generally a question that describes what you have done and where you are getting stuck will result in higher quality responses.

Are you asking to repeat a column, or a row, as you show in the question? In either case, how many times?

Using Office 365 you could approach it with TOCOL:
=TOCOL(IF({1,2,3,4},A1:A4))
Or
=TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,4),A1:A4))

The horizontal array of integers ({1,1,1,1} would work just as well) converts to TRUE inside IF and since it's horizontal, unlike the range, it copies the row's value along to the side; same for next row's value, etc.
If this array is wrapped in TOCOL it gets flattened, so the repeated values are underneath eachother.
And for older Excel versions this is a way:
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,ROUNDUP(ROW(1:1)/4,)),"")
(Needs dragging down)
You may even want to add a blank line in between different values. Using the same kind of logic as the Office 365 solution you can accomplish this using:
=DROP(TOCOL(IF({1,1,1,1,0},A1:A4,"")),-1)
Or dynamically:
=LET(n,4,DROP(TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,n+1,n,-1),A1:A4,"")),-1))

If it's a one time thing:

make a helper column, numbering each item 1,2,3... and so on

Copy both columns




Paste them four times, one below the other



Sort on the numbers



Delete the helper columns

If this is a repeating task you may want to consider automating this with a macro

The OP clearly states, "Now, obviously I can just ctrl c, drag mouse over 4 cells, and ctrl v. But the actual list that I am wanting to use is like 1000 values long..."

And? The solution I put forward uses the same number of steps whether you have 4 or 4000 rows. And does not depend on having the latest version of Excel
